Why am I getting answer with AUTHORITY flag set to zero in BIND DNS Server configuration even though my server is authoritative for that domain?
https://fedoramagazine.org/how-to-setup-a-dns-server-with-bind/
I setup DNS server in bind as per this article
Master=192.168.1.206=master.example.com
Client=192.168.1.3=client.example.com

//
// /etc/named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
    #listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.1.2; };
    #listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
    recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
    allow-query     { localhost; 192.168.1.0/24; };

    /* 
     - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
     - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable 
       recursion. 
     - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access 
       control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
       cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification 
       attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
       reduce such attack surface 
    */
    recursion yes;

    #dnssec-validation yes;

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
    geoip-directory "/usr/share/GeoIP";

    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";

    /* https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/CryptoPolicy */
    include "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

zone "example.com" IN {
type master;
file "forward";
allow-update { none; };
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
type master;
file "reverse";
allow-update { none; };
};

I setup forward and reverse zone file as this.
#forward

$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     master.example.com. admin.example.com. (
                2023010401  ;Serial
                3600        ;Refresh
                1800        ;Retry
                604800      ;Expire
                86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

@               IN      NS      master.example.com.
@           IN  A       192.168.1.206
@           IN  A       192.168.1.3
@           IN  A       192.168.1.4
master          IN  A       192.168.1.206
webserver       IN  A       192.168.1.4

#reverse

$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     master.example.com. admin.example.com. (
                2023010401  ;Serial
                3600        ;Refresh
                1800        ;Retry
                604800      ;Expire
                86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

@               IN  NS      master.example.com.
@           IN  PTR     example.com.
master          IN  A       192.168.1.206
webserver       IN  A       192.168.1.4
206         IN  PTR     master.example.com.
4           IN  PTR     webserver.example.com.

Then I setup /etc/resolv.conf to this in master server
search example.com
nameserver 192.168.1.206

Now I go to master and do
dig example.com

I get the answer but I get AUTHORITY=0
[root@dns01 named]# dig example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.23-RH <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55501
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: b15240d00532152a010000006623f6970bb37622180b1f28 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.            IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.     86400   IN      A       192.168.1.3
example.com.     86400   IN      A       192.168.1.206
example.com.     86400   IN      A       192.168.1.4

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.206#53(192.168.1.206)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 20 18:08:39 WEST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 123


If your system is using systemd-resolved, your /etc/resolv.conf might be getting rewritten to point to nameserver 127.0.0.53, the caching resolver of systemd-resolved. That might explain the non-authoritative answer: you may be getting it from the resolver's cache.
(If that is happening, it is a sign that you should regard /etc/resolv.conf on that system as an obsolete configuration file that exists for legacy compatibility only. See resolvectl for real DNS resolver settings in that case.)
Try explicitly telling dig to connect directly to the authoritative server, rather than relying on defaults:
dig example.com @192.168.1.206

